# Can't advanced search with SKU hyphen in magento?

Tags: php, magento

i'm new to magento ,took me few days but still can't fix this problem , i'm using magento 2.3.4 now i want to use advanced search to search configurable product base on SKUs

if SKUs no hyphen , it worked

[image]

but if SKUs have hyphen , it cannot find that product

[image]

but if i use quicksearch , it still can search that product

[image]

trying debug in module-elasticsearch/Elasticsearch5/SearchAdapter/Mapper.php
quicksearch it use match key
[image]

but advanced search it use wildcard

[image]

trying to delete sku filter in search_request.xml but no result too . Maybe it the reason ? anyone can give me a direction or solution to fix that problem ? Thanks for reading

Comment: You have to apply the Patches MDVA-28357 and maybe MDVA-28993.